Socket.IO Client in Production Tries to Connect to :3000 Instead of the Specified URL
I am using Socket.IO in a React application, and everything works perfectly in development. However, when I deploy the application to the production environment, I notice that the Socket.IO client attempts to connect to wss://mydomain.com:3000/ws, even though I have not configured this URL or port in my code.
Environment Details:
Frontend: React (built with create-react-app)
Backend: Node.js with Socket.IO
Hosting: AWS (both frontend and backend)
In production, the browser's Network tab shows repeated WebSocket connection attempts to:
wss://mydomain.com:3000/ws
These requests fail, and the WebSocket connection never establishes. Here’s the error from the browser console:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com:3000/ws' faile
The https connection to backend is successful but the console shows the error related to wss request.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
